# adding RequiredFieldValidator at runtime

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I am adding controls to the page as well as the `RequiredFieldValidator` controls, but something is going wrong.

```
    int i = 4; // for testing; for now
    // add surname textbox
    PlaceHolderResidents.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"control-group\">"));

    TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
    tb1.ID = "LastName" + i;
    tb1.CssClass = "input-xlarge";
    labelLastName.AssociatedControlID = tb1.ID;

    PlaceHolderResidents.Controls.Add(labelLastName);
    PlaceHolderResidents.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"controls\">"));
    PlaceHolderResidents.Controls.Add(tb1);

    RequiredFieldValidator rfv1 = new RequiredFieldValidator();
    rfv1.ControlToValidate = tb1.ID; // ERROR HERE
    rfv1.ErrorMessage = GetLocalResourceObject("RequiredFieldValidator_LastNameResource.ErrorMessage").ToString();
    PlaceHolderResidents.Controls.Add(rfv1);
```

I am getting an error

`System.Web.HttpException: Unable to find control id 'LastName4' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of ''.`

This code is placed in `Page_Load()`, but I tried placing it in other `Page` events without success. Any ideas? Thank you.

EDIT:
Full code for this section.

```
            PlaceHolderResidents.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\n\n<div class=\"control-group\">"));
    Label labelLastName = new Label();
    labelLastName.Text = GetLocalResourceObject("LastNameLabelResource.Text").ToString();
    labelLastName.CssClass = "control-label asterisk";
    TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
    tb1.ID = "LastName" + i;
    tb1.CssClass = "input-xlarge";
    labelLastName.AssociatedControlID = tb1.ID;
    PlaceHolderResidents.Controls.Add(labelLastName);
    PlaceHolderResidents.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\n<div class=\"controls\">"));
    PlaceHolderResidents.Controls.Add(tb1);
    PlaceHolderResidents.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\n<p class=\"help-block\">"));
    RequiredFieldValidator rfv1 = new RequiredFieldValidator();
    rfv1.ControlToValidate = tb1.ID;
    rfv1.ErrorMessage = GetLocalResourceObject("RequiredFieldValidator_LastNameResource.ErrorMessage").ToString();
    rfv1.EnableClientScript = false;
    PlaceHolderResidents.Controls.Add(rfv1);
    PlaceHolderResidents.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\n</p></div></div>"));
```

It is interesting to note that I have more of these validators on the page and most of them are working. If I comment out the code above many validators on the page work (there is one another `RequiredFieldValidator` that gives the same error for some reason).

EDIT 2: The code above works. Not sure what was wrong.

Comment: Your code is working fine. Please post the rest of the code.

Comment: I pasted the problematic code.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, you can't access that directly. You might have to use "FindControl()" method as shown below.

```
RequiredFieldValidator rfv1 = new RequiredFieldValidator();
rfv1.ControlToValidate = PlaceHolderResidents.FindControl(tb1.ID);
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I tried this `rfv1.ControlToValidate = ((TextBox)PlaceHolderResidents.FindControl(tb1.ID)).ID` but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Nope. Same error `Unable to find control id 'LastName4' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of ''.` It appears something is wrong with validator itself.

Comment: Is PlaceHolderResidents a Panel Control in .aspx?

Comment: It is the Panel control in .aspx.

Comment: I was not getting any error with the same code that you have provided here.

Comment: This is weird. I also tested only the code above and it works for some reason. I'm going to paste the complete code for only this section.

Comment: Your username `System.Collections.Generic` is really confusing in the comment area.

Comment: I pasted the code that gives error. Many other same validators work there is one more validator that gives same error.

Comment: I copied the working code and changed the variable names for the section in question and everything works now. The code is identical to what's pasted above. Don't know what was wrong. Thank you everybody for participating.